# Function that produce a spike in 3D

Tags: visualization

I am looking for a function that would produce a spike, of any size, in the z-direction at a given x and y coordinate. A little bit like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function but that could be graphed in 3D.

I am not sure if those specifications are clear, if not please let me know I will clarify according to feedback.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing it, but a 'nice' way (continuous, infinitely differentiable) would be to consider a pulse as a normal distribution with close to zero variance, that is

$$z = A\exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

You can keep taking variances smaller and smaller till you get the desired result

Comment: Thanks Dhanvi, so something like this? https://www.geogebra.org/3d/rzh7bqms

Comment: What is `A` here? Also, x_0 and y_0 are the desired coordinates right?

Comment: A is a scaling factor, to get the height of the pulse

Comment: In the link, you need to eponentiate it. something like this: https://www.geogebra.org/3d/rzh7bqms

Comment: The smaller your variance, the sharper the pulse

Comment: Something like this https://www.geogebra.org/3d/rzh7bqms? (the that you shared didn't' update)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109385/discussion-between-silkadmin-and-dhanvi-sreenivasan).